# Objective c string formatter for meter/cm and feet/inches

Tags: ios, cocoa, nsstring, distance, formatter

I have a distance as a float and I'm looking for a way to format it nicely for human readers. Ideally, I'd like it to change from meters(3.02) to 3m and 2cm, and to round the number nicely. Same for feet value(e.g 2.03f) to 2'.36'' and to round .36inches to number.

idea in my mind is to use string formatter like:

```
[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d'%.0f\"",someIntValue,decimalVa];
return [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%dm %.0fcm", someIntValue,decimalVa];
```

If there's no code available, how can I write my own formatter?

Thanks

Comment: Try looking at `HKUnit`, which should cover this.

Comment: HKUnit is better but it is not changing to string literals like the way i want. Could you please elaborate some more on this.?